# Using the intuitive idea of the "generalized" Pigeonhole Principle

Tags: real-analysis

On page 21 of Royden's book, Real Analysis 2nd Edition, we find exercise 24 which says:

Let $f$ be a function from a set $X$ to the collection $\mathbb{P} (X)$ of subsets of $X$. Then there is a set $E \subset X$ which is not in the range of $f$.

Hint: Let $E=\{x:x\notin f(x)\}$

Using the hint it becomes easy to solve, but the first time I saw the exercise it was not in the book, therefore I never saw the hint and I tried to use the pigeonhole principle in a somewhat intuitive way, still not knowing if it had a version for the infinite case, then I saw yes but the number of boxes is always finite. My question is, even for the infinite case it is true that $|\mathbb{P} (X)| \geq |X|$?

And if so, can I then use this intuitive idea to solve the exercise?

Comment: The result of the exercise is true for finite and infinite sets (the proof implied by the hint is  independent of the size of $X$). In fact the result implies that $|\Bbb{P}(X)| > |X|$ (strictly greater) for any set $X$ (given a suitable definition of cardinality for all sets).

Comment: Rob Arthan, is true that the result of the excercise works for finite cases also, and in that case piggeonhole principle can be used, so I omitted that case. Also the inequality is strictly greater because the empty set is always a subset of any set, I made a little mistake while writing. So, according to your answer, what I´m trying to use, is the result of the exercise itself?